# Is it possible to hide the shipping method step on magento checkout process

Tags: php, magento, checkout, cart

Is it possible to hide the shipping method step on the magento checkout process. I want to remove the shipping method step only on checkout page, not permanently.

What i am trying to achieve is on the cart page when the customer enters his postcode for shipping estimate and then update total. I will want to use his choice he made here for his order. So I see no relevance for him to alter his shipping choice afterwards as I only have one shipping option.

I have searched around and found there are ways of removing the step altogether and enabling a default shipping method. However I am using a table matrix so the shipping charge differs based on postcode entered, so i can not set it as a default.

Please can you advice if it is possible to achieve what I want and if so how would I approach it.

Advice and guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?
Have you tried this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85181/how-to-hide-shipping-method-in-magento ?

Comment: Hi @Nikhil Thanks for replying. I have followed code by Marius. However i am getting invalid shipping method. I am using the Table Rates Matrix by WebShopApp and i am using the the following for the default method line. Please advise. '<default_shipping>matrixrate_matrixrate</default_shipping>'